# Why model weights trained on google colab cannot perform locally as in colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

Recently I trained my model on google colab and saved weights in google drive automatically by ModelCheckPoint.

**When I use these saved weights on google colab the prediction performs great, but when I download the weights and run them locally on my laptop, the prediction is extemely terrible.**

The GPU of my laptop is GeForce RTX 1060 with Max-Q design 12GB. Could anyone tell me what leads to the different performance between my laptop and google colab?

By the way, I tried to save the whole model and then load it, the saving process runs smoothly but when I load model, there is a **ValueError** says **"There is a cyclic-dependency between functions"**, still have no idea how to solve it.

Comment: I re-saved the model weights after my model loaded weights locally and then uploaded this weight file to google drive, when I use this weight in colab, the model also shows terrible performance, so I guess there is something wrong when I load weights locally and then my model didn't load those weights correctly. Still don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by changing tensorflow-gpu==2.2.0 to tensorflow==2.3.0, which is extactly the same as the version in google colab.

Comment: I was going to suggest that thought they might be running a different version of tensorflow.